Accesar a una propiedad strict private utilizando herencia en Delphi
El problema que tengo es el siguiente:
Tengo una clase llamada TEscuela con la siguiente estructura:
unit Escuela;

interface
uses Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Sysutils, Vcl.dialogs, DataSnap.DBClient;
type

    TEscuela = class
    private
        Fnombre: String;
        Festado: String;
        procedure Setnombre(val: String);
        procedure Setestado(val: String);
    public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
        property nombre: String read Fnombre write Setnombre;
        property estado: String read Festado write Setestado;
    function altaEscuelaProcedencia:String; virtual;abstract;
    function bajaEscuelaProcedencia:String; virtual;abstract;
    function cambiaEscuelaProcedencia:String; virtual;abstract;
    function regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado:TDataset; virtual;abstract;
    strict private
            sp: TADOStoredProc;
  end;


implementation
uses BD;

constructor TEscuela.Create;
    var
        BD: TBd;
    begin
        inherited Create;
        BD := TBd.GetInstance;
        try
            try
                sp := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
                // Se regresa la conexión a la base de datos
                sp.Connection := BD.regresaConexion;
            except
                on e: Exception do
                    ShowMessage(e.message);
            end;
        finally
            //BD.Destroy;
        end;
    end;

destructor TEscuela.Destroy;
    begin
        inherited Destroy;
    end;



procedure TEscuela.Setnombre(val: String);
    begin
        Fnombre:=val;
    end;

    procedure TEscuela.Setestado(val: String);
    begin
        Festado:=val;
    end;

    end.

Y tengo una clase hija llamada TEscuelaProcedencia con la siguiente estructura:
unit EscuelaProcedencia;

interface
uses Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Sysutils, Vcl.dialogs, DataSnap.DBClient, Escuela;
type

    TEscuelaProcedencia = class(TEscuela)
    private
    public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
    function altaEscuelaProcedencia:String; override;
    function bajaEscuelaProcedencia:String; override;
    function cambiaEscuelaProcedencia:String; override;
    function regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado:TDataset; override;
    strict private
            sp: TADOStoredProc;
  end;


implementation
uses BD;
function TEscuelaProcedencia.altaEscuelaProcedencia: String;
begin
                inherited Create;
        if nombre = '' then
            begin
                result := 'Debe escribir el nombre de la escuela';
            end
        else
            begin
                try
                    sp.ProcedureName := 'sc.spAltaEscuelaProcedencia';
                    sp.Parameters.Refresh;
                    sp.Parameters.Items[1].Value := nombre;
                    sp.Parameters.Items[2].Value := estado;
                    sp.ExecProc;
                    result := 'OK';
                except
                    on e: Exception do
                        begin
                            if pos('IX_nombre_idEntidadFederativa_CE_ESCUELA_PROCEDENCIA', e.message) > 0 then
                                begin
                                    result := 'Ya existe la escuela en es estado';
                                end
                            else
                                begin
                                    result := e.message;
                                end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
end;

function TEscuelaProcedencia.bajaEscuelaProcedencia: String;
begin

end;

function TEscuelaProcedencia.cambiaEscuelaProcedencia: String;
begin

end;

constructor TEscuelaProcedencia.Create;
    begin
        inherited Create;
    sp:=sp;
    end;

destructor TEscuelaProcedencia.Destroy;
    begin
        inherited Destroy;
    end;

    function TEscuelaProcedencia.regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado: TDataset;
begin
sp.Close;
sp.ProcedureName := 'sc.[spRegresaEscuelaProcedenciaEstado]';
sp.Parameters.Refresh;
sp.Parameters.Items[1].Value := estado;
sp.Open;
result := sp;
end;

    end.

En el constructor de la clase padre, estoy utilizando el patrón SINGLETON para hacer la conexión a la BD:
constructor TEscuela.Create;
    var
        BD: TBd;
    begin
        inherited Create;
        BD := TBd.GetInstance;
        try
            try
                sp := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
                // Se regresa la conexión a la base de datos
                sp.Connection := BD.regresaConexion;
            except
                on e: Exception do
                    ShowMessage(e.message);
            end;
        finally
            //BD.Destroy;
        end;
    end;


Y esa conexión la utilizo para ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en mi BD que me regresa un Dataset( function TEscuelaProcedencia.regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado: TDataset;), sin embargo, cuando llego a llamar al objeto sp, marca un error de memoria y este es el error: Project program.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION"
¿Cómo podría hacer que tenga acceso a la conexión creada desde la clase padre a la hija y poder usarla en esa función y las demás?

"marca un error de memoria". ¿Qué error específicamente (mensaje de error exacto, clase de la excepción), y en qué línea del código ocurre la excepción?

Este es el error: Project program.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION"

creo que esa información pertenece a la pregunta, y no a los comentarios, te pido que le des clic en [edit] y la añadas.  Vendría muy bien también saber en que línea del código se produce. Tu código tiene varios problemas, pero es mejor escribir una respuesta que te ayude a resolver ese error, que una que abarque todos los posibles problemas que puedes tener, aunque haría falta mencionar algunos. Un saludo.

Deberías ejecutar paso a paso tu aplicación, utilizar puntos de ruptura (breakpoints) y detectar la línea donde se produce el error.
Una vez detectado la línea exacta revisa las variables y objetos que estás utilizando en esa línea para ver si alguno llega sin inicializar (si llega a nil).
Algunas cosas más acerca del tu código;
Este Create es innecesario:
constructor TEscuelaProcedencia.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  sp:=sp;
end;

Si llamas al inherited con los mismos parámetros no hace falta llamarlo como:
  inherited Create;

sólo como:
  inherited;

Por otro lado estás utilizando variables sp, tanto en la clase TEscuela como en TEscuelaProcedencia. Eso te va a dar problemas y es inneccesario. Define la variable en la clase base como protected y la tendrás disponible en ambas.
Al realizar esta asignación en el Create va a provocar que la segunda variable pierda su apuntador, puesto que lo estás sustituyendo por el apuntador de la primera variable sp:
sp := sp;

Eso es lo que te está provocando el Access Violation.

ya lo hice y si entra a la clase padre y si crea la conexión y se lo asigna al sp en esta linea:  sp.Connection := BD.regresaConexion; El problema es que cuando entro a la función TEscuelaProcedencia.regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado: TDataset; de la clase hija, en esta linea, marca el error: sp.Close; que mencioné arriba.

ya lo hice y si entra a la clase padre y si crea la conexión y se lo asigna al sp en esta linea:  sp.Connection := BD.regresaConexion; El problema es que cuando entró a la función TEscuelaProcedencia.regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado: TDataset; de la clase hija, en esta linea marca el error: sp.Close; Project program.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tendrías que mirar si en ese punto (del Access Violation) la variable sp está asignada o vale nil. Edito la respuesta para comentarte algunas cosas más.

Hola Nefatalí:
Gracias por tus comentarios e hice las modificaciones que me recomendaste.
La línea donde marca el error es sp.close y es nil el valor en la funcion function TEscuelaProcedencia.regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado: TDataset;

Revisa las modificaciones que he realizado en la respuesta. Creo que al tener 2 variables sp y asignarlas estás perdiendo la referencia y por eso te la encuentras a nil. Una de esas 2 variables sobre.

Hola Neftalí: Hice los cambios que me indicaste y aún marca el mismo error y en la misma linea: sp.close de la función TEscuelaProcedencia.regresaEscuelasProcedenciaEstado: TDataset; . Removí el sp de la clase hija.

Ya quedo arreglado y todo fue porque en el evento "Create" de la clase hija tenia que dejar solo  inherited:
constructor TEscuelaProcedencia.Create;
begin
  inherited;

end;

Gracias a todos por sus comentarios.

Sólo comentar que el Create con el inherited (sólo) y con los mismos parámetros que el método del que hereda, puede eliminarlo.
